# PAMI Asterisk ami Error reading

Tags: php, asterisk

В библиотеке `PAMI` есть метод класса `PAMI\Client\Impl\ClientImpl->getMessages()` которая читает из сокета данные. Но в некоторый момент вылетает с ошибкой

> Error reading.

После обработки данного исключения я перезапускаю скрипт но за время переподключения теряются некоторые важные для меня события. Может кто нибудь подскажет в чем проблема? Как сделать что бы скрипт не вылетал.(Если допустим не выбрасывать исключение и не перезапускать скрипт(переподключаясь к `AMI`) то просто перестает читать данные из сокета).

```
<?php
declare(ticks=1);
namespace PAMI\Client\Impl;

use PAMI\Message\Action\EventsAction;
use PAMI\Message\OutgoingMessage;
use PAMI\Message\Message;
use PAMI\Message\IncomingMessage;
use PAMI\Message\Action\LoginAction;
use PAMI\Message\Action\LogoffAction;
use PAMI\Message\Response\ResponseMessage;
use PAMI\Message\Event\EventMessage;
use PAMI\Message\Event\Factory\Impl\EventFactoryImpl;
use PAMI\Listener\IEventListener;
use PAMI\Client\Exception\ClientException;
use PAMI\Client\IClient;



class ClientImpl implements IClient
{

private $_logger;

/**
 * Hostname
 * @var string
 */
private $_host;

/**
 * TCP Port.
 * @var integer
 */
private $_port;

/**
 * Username
 * @var string
 */
private $_user;

/**
 * Password
 * @var string
 */
private $_pass;

/**
 * Connection timeout, in seconds.
 * @var integer
 */
private $_cTimeout;

/**
 * Connection scheme, like tcp:// or tls://
 * @var string
 */
private $_scheme;

/**
 * Event factory.
 * @var EventFactoryImpl
 */
private $_eventFactory;

/**
 * R/W timeout, in milliseconds.
 * @var integer
 */
private $_rTimeout;

/**
 * Our stream socket resource.
 * @var resource
 */
private $_socket;

/**
 * Our stream context resource.
 * @var resource
 */
private $_context;

/**
 * Our event listeners
 * @var IEventListener[]
 */
private $_eventListeners;

/**
 * The send queue
 * @var OutgoingMessage[]
 */
private $_outgoingQueue;

/**
 * The receiving queue.
 * @var IncomingMessage[]
 */
private $_incomingQueue;

/**
 * Our current received message. May be incomplete, will be completed
 * eventually with an EOM.
 * @var string
 */
private $_currentProcessingMessage;

/**
 * This should not happen. Asterisk may send responses without a
 * corresponding ActionId.
 * @var string
 */
private $_lastActionId;

/**
 * Opens a tcp connection to ami.
 *
 * @throws PAMI\Client\Exception\ClientException
 * @return void
 */
public function open()
{
    $cString = $this->_scheme . $this->_host . ':' . $this->_port;
    $this->_context = stream_context_create();
    $errno = 0;
    $errstr = '';
    $this->_socket = @stream_socket_client(
        $cString, $errno, $errstr,
        $this->_cTimeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $this->_context
    );
    if ($this->_socket === false) {
        throw new ClientException('Error connecting to ami: ' . $errstr);
    }
    $msg = new LoginAction($this->_user, $this->_pass);
       $id = @stream_get_line($this->_socket, 1024, Message::EOL);
    if (strstr($id, 'Asterisk') === false) {
        throw new ClientException('Unknown peer. Is this an ami?: ' . $id);
    }
    $response = $this->send($msg);
    if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
        throw new ClientException('Could not connect: ' . $response->getMessage());
    }

    /*add setfilter*/
    $filter = new EventsAction(array('call'));
    $response = $this->send($filter);
    if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
        throw new ClientException('Not set event filter on open: ' . $response->getMessage());
    }

    @stream_set_blocking($this->_socket, 0);
    $this->_currentProcessingMessage = '';
    //register_tick_function(array($this, 'process'));
    if ($this->_logger->isDebugEnabled()) {
        $this->_logger->debug('Logged in successfully to ami.');
    }
}

/**
 * Registers the given listener so it can receive events. Returns the generated
 * id for this new listener. You can pass in a an IEventListener, a Closure,
 * and an array containing the object and name of the method to invoke. Can specify
 * an optional predicate to invoke before calling the callback.
 *
 * @param mixed $listener
 * @param Closure|null $predicate
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function registerEventListener($listener, $predicate = null)
{
    $id = uniqid('PamiListener');
    $this->_eventListeners[$id] = array($listener, $predicate);
    return $id;
}

/**
 * Unregisters an event listener.
 *
 * @param string $id The id returned by registerEventListener.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function unregisterEventListener($id)
{
    if (isset($this->_eventListeners[$id])) {
        unset($this->_eventListeners[$id]);
    }
}

/**
 * Reads a complete message over the stream until EOM.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getMessages()
{
    $msgs = array();

    // Read something.
    $read = @fread($this->_socket, 65535);
    if ($read === false || @feof($this->_socket)) {
        echo "empty data";
        throw new ClientException('Error reading');
    }



    $this->_currentProcessingMessage .= $read;


    echo $this->_currentProcessingMessage.PHP_EOL;
    echo stream_get_meta_data($this->_socket);

    // If we have a complete message, then return it. Save the rest for
    // later.
    while (($marker = strpos($this->_currentProcessingMessage, Message::EOM))) {
        $msg = substr($this->_currentProcessingMessage, 0, $marker);
        $this->_currentProcessingMessage = substr(
            $this->_currentProcessingMessage, $marker + strlen(Message::EOM)
        );
        $msgs[] = $msg;
    }
    return $msgs;
}

/**
 * Main processing loop. Also called from send(), you should call this in
 * your own application in order to continue reading events and responses
 * from ami. 
 */
public function process()
{
    $msgs = $this->getMessages();
    foreach ($msgs as $aMsg) {
        if ($this->_logger->isDebugEnabled()) {
            $this->_logger->debug(
                '------ Received: ------ ' . "\n" . $aMsg . "\n\n"
            );
        }
        $resPos = strpos($aMsg, 'Response:');
        $evePos = strpos($aMsg, 'Event:');
        if (($resPos !== false) && (($resPos < $evePos) || $evePos === false)) {
            $response = $this->_messageToResponse($aMsg);
            $this->_incomingQueue[$response->getActionId()] = $response;
        } else if ($evePos !== false) {
            $event = $this->_messageToEvent($aMsg);
            $response = $this->findResponse($event);
            if ($response === false || $response->isComplete()) {
                $this->dispatch($event);
            } else {
                $response->addEvent($event);
            }
        } else {
            // broken ami.. sending a response with events without
            // Event and ActionId
            $bMsg = 'Event: ResponseEvent' . "\r\n";
            $bMsg .= 'ActionId: ' . $this->_lastActionId . "\r\n" . $aMsg;
            $event = $this->_messageToEvent($bMsg);
            $response = $this->findResponse($event);
            $response->addEvent($event);
        }
        if ($this->_logger->isDebugEnabled()) {
            $this->_logger->debug('----------------');
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Tries to find an associated response for the given message.
 *
 * @param IncomingMessage $message Message sent by asterisk.
 *
 * @return PAMI\Message\Response\ResponseMessage
 */
protected function findResponse(IncomingMessage $message)
{
    $actionId = $message->getActionId();
    if (isset($this->_incomingQueue[$actionId])) {
        return $this->_incomingQueue[$actionId];
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Dispatchs the incoming message to a handler.
 *
 * @param PAMI\Message\IncomingMessage $message Message to dispatch.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function dispatch(IncomingMessage $message)
{
    foreach ($this->_eventListeners as $data) {
        $listener = $data[0];
        $predicate = $data[1];
        if ($predicate !== null && !$predicate($message)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($listener instanceof \Closure) {
            $listener($message);
        } else if (is_array($listener)) {
            $listener[0]->$listener[1]($message);
        } else {
            $listener->handle($message);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Returns a ResponseMessage from a raw string that came from asterisk.
 *
 * @param string $msg Raw string.
 *
 * @return PAMI\Message\Response\ResponseMessage
 */
private function _messageToResponse($msg)
{
    $response = new ResponseMessage($msg);
    $actionId = $response->getActionId();
    if ($actionId === null) {
        $actionId = $this->_lastActionId;
        $response->setActionId($this->_lastActionId);
    }
    return $response;
}

/**
 * Returns a EventMessage from a raw string that came from asterisk.
 *
 * @param string $msg Raw string.
 *
 * @return PAMI\Message\Event\EventMessage
 */
private function _messageToEvent($msg)
{
    return $this->_eventFactory->createFromRaw($msg);
}

/**
 * Returns a message (response) related to the given message. This uses
 * the ActionID tag (key).
 *
 * @todo not suitable for multithreaded applications.
 *
 * @return PAMI\Message\IncomingMessage
 */
protected function getRelated(OutgoingMessage $message)
{
    $ret = false;
    $id = $message->getActionID('ActionID');
    if (isset($this->_incomingQueue[$id])) {
        $response = $this->_incomingQueue[$id];
        if ($response->isComplete()) {
            unset($this->_incomingQueue[$id]);
            $ret = $response;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

/**
 * Sends a message to ami.
 *
 * @param PAMI\Message\OutgoingMessage $message Message to send.
 *
 * @see ClientImpl::send()
 * @throws PAMI\Client\Exception\ClientException
 * @return PAMI\Message\Response\ResponseMessage
 */
public function send(OutgoingMessage $message)
{
    $messageToSend = $message->serialize();
    $length = strlen($messageToSend);
    if ($this->_logger->isDebugEnabled()) {
        $this->_logger->debug(
            '------ Sending: ------ ' . "\n" . $messageToSend . '----------'
        );
    }
    $this->_lastActionId = $message->getActionId();
    if (@fwrite($this->_socket, $messageToSend) < $length) {
        throw new ClientException('Could not send message');
    }
    $read = 0;
    while($read <= $this->_rTimeout) {
        $this->process();
        $response = $this->getRelated($message);
        if ($response != false) {
            $this->_lastActionId = false;
            return $response;
        }
        usleep(1000); // 1ms delay
        if ($this->_rTimeout > 0) {
            $read++;
        }
    }
    throw new ClientException('Read timeout');
}

/**
 * Closes the connection to ami.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function close()
{
    if ($this->_logger->isDebugEnabled()) {
        $this->_logger->debug('Closing connection to asterisk.');
    }
    @stream_socket_shutdown($this->_socket, STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);
}

/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param string[] $options Options for ami client.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(array $options)
{
    if (isset($options['log4php.properties'])) {
        \Logger::configure($options['log4php.properties']);
    }
    $this->_logger = \Logger::getLogger('Pami.ClientImpl');
    $this->_host = $options['host'];
    $this->_port = intval($options['port']);
    $this->_user = $options['username'];
    $this->_pass = $options['secret'];
    $this->_cTimeout = $options['connect_timeout'];
    $this->_rTimeout = $options['read_timeout'];
    $this->_scheme = isset($options['scheme']) ? $options['scheme'] : 'tcp://';
    $this->_eventListeners = array();
    $this->_eventFactory = new EventFactoryImpl();
    $this->_incomingQueue = array();
    $this->_lastActionId = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Исходя из опыта, Asterisk свойственно без какой-либо причины закрывать соединение (У нас несколько раз уже была такая проблема, возникающая чаще всего в период, когда на АТС нет вообще никакой активности. Причину мы так и не выявили, но, очень похоже, что это каким-то образом связано с тем, что периодически отваливаются транки одного из провайдеров). Я вместо вывода исключения настраивал переподключение плюс, для надежности, shell-скрипт (watchdog), который следит за процессом и запускает его заново в случае падения. Способ, вероятно, не самый красивый, но позволяет получать данные из AMI с минимальными потерями.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то вы очень странно используете PAMI. Выложу кусок своего кода работы со звёздочкой

```
private $options = array(
    'host' => '192.168.0.1',
    'scheme' => 'tcp://',
    'port' => 5038,
    'username' => 'username',
    'secret' => ' secret',
    'connect_timeout' => 10000,
    'read_timeout' => 10000
);
// use PAMI\Client\Impl\ClientImpl as PamiClient;
$this->asterisk = new PamiClient($this->options);
// use React\EventLoop\Factory;
$this->loop = Factory::create();
// class AsteriskEventListener implements IEventListener
$this->asterisk->registerEventListener(new AsteriskEventListener($this->server),
                function (EventMessage $event) {
            return $event instanceof NewstateEvent
                    || $event instanceof HangupEvent
                    || $event instanceof OriginateResponseEvent;
        });

$this->asterisk->open();

$this->loop->addPeriodicTimer($this->interval, function () use ($asterisk, $retries) {
      try {
           $asterisk->process();
      } catch (Exception $exc) {
           if ($retries-- <= 0) {
               throw new \RuntimeException('Exit from loop', 1, $exc);
           }
           sleep(10);
      }
});
```